# How to make Hawtio to connect to remote jolokia using query parameters

Tags: hawtio

We have a number of applications with jolokia and single instance of hawtio to monitor all of them. Now we want to have a link on application's web page pointing to that hawtio console. By clicking on this link we would like hawtio to connect to this application automatically. Is it possible to somehow provide hawtio with connection details so it can connect to the application? Something like http://host:post/hawtio/?con=myapp&host=apphost&port=... Or maybe there's other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No but there is a ticket about this at:

- https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/1965

And a bit 'hacky' PR here:

- https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/pull/2077